# Error using WSO2 peoplehr connector

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am trying to use [WSO2 peoplehr connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/PeopleHR+Connector) and my proxy service is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="peopleHrEmployeeDetails" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <peoplehr.getEmployee configKey="employee"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

and the local entry is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="employee" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <peoplehr.init>
    <apiUrl>https://api.peoplehr.net/</apiUrl>
    <apiKey>c85c2570-0602-4930-a0c7-847c1a26550c</apiKey>
    <employeeId>PW5</employeeId>
  </peoplehr.init>
</localEntry>
```

and I have enabled the peoplehr connector on the WSO2 ESB. When I deploy the proxy service on the WSO2 ESB and try it using the tryit tool with nothing in the body of the message I get lot of exceptions in the WSO2 server and the message is not sent.

```
2015-11-15 21:56:28,933] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
[2015-11-15 21:56:28,942]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-11-15 21:56:28,944]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Sun Nov 15 21:56:58 IST 2015
[2015-11-15 21:57:28,572]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://riyafa-Dell-System-Vostro-3450:8280/services/peopleHrEmployeeDetails.peopleHrEmployeeDetailsHttpSoap12Endpoint]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is [under construction](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/PeopleHR+Connector) for that connector, and probably don't have enough information to set up. There is a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-2263) reported already. We will be fixing this in future.

It seems, you have to get the PeopleHR's public key certificate and add it into client-truststore.jks.

Please follow the documentation from connector's github repo [here](https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/blob/master/peoplehr/peoplehr-connector/peoplehr-connector-1.0.0/README.txt)